# Store pointer to 2d array

Tags: c++, arrays

So I have a private member in the class `Map`:

```
char **_map;
```

I then try to initialize the pointer array to a two dimensional `char` array like this:

```
std::vector<std::string> contents = StringUtils::split(_mapInfo.getContents(), ' ');
const int x = StringUtils::toInt(contents.at(0));
const int y = StringUtils::toInt(contents.at(1));
_map = new char[x][y];
```

Basically the `contents` vector contains two strings, which I then convert into integers. I then try to initialize the `map` array but I receive this error:

```
Error   1   error C2540: non-constant expression as array bound
```

And this:

```
Error   2   error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'char (*)[1]' to 'char **'
```

And finally this:

```
    3   IntelliSense: expression must have a constant value
```

The last error references the variable `y`

Can anyone explain what is happening and how I can fix it?

Comment: This question has been answered in [How do I declare a 2d array in C++ using new?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/936687/how-do-i-declare-a-2d-array-in-c-using-new)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initialization of 2d array is as following;

```
char **_map;

_map = new char*[rowsize];

for(int row = 0; row < rowsize; ++row)
{
    _map[row] = new char[columnsize]
}
```